# Can I invoke a java method other than main(String[]) from the command line?

Tags: java, methods

Can I invoke a java method other than `main(String[])` from the command line?

Comment: If you install a REPL for a JVM language (Groovy probably takes the least work to get started with), then you can invoke Java methods at the REPL prompt (Groovy's is called groovysh).

Comment: @NathanHughes I wish that you had left that as an answer. It was exactly what I needed. Can you repost it as an answer?

Comment: The REPL idea totally works - you can use Beanshell for example to load any class from any jar, and call any method on any class. And you can do it by just dropping the beanshell jar on a machine, and using it interactively or with a script file, which itself is pretty much java. Nice simple example showing how to do this [can be found here](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/10/17/beanshell-tutorial-quick-start-on-invoking-your-own-or-external-java-code-from-the-shell/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you install a REPL for a JVM language (Groovy probably takes the least work to get started with), then you can invoke Java methods at the REPL prompt (Groovy's is called groovysh). `groovysh` has some odd features (my least favorite bit is that declaring variables with `def` doesn't do what you'd think it should) but it's still really useful. It's an interesting feature that Groovy doesn't respect privacy, so you can call private methods and check the contents of private variables.

Groovy installs include groovysh. Download the zip file, extract it somewhere, add the location of the bin directory to the path and you're good to go. You can drop jars into the lib folder, for the code you're running and libraries used by that code, and Groovy will find them there.

Comment: REPL was exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing me to it. Changed my life. LoL. no.. really.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't have a main function, you can just add one, and if you do, you can just add a series of if-then blocks to the top.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args[0].equals("MY_METHOD"))
        callMyMethod();
    else if(args[0].equals("MY_OTHER_METHOD"))
        callMyOtherMethod();
    //... Repeat ad nauseum...
    else {
        //Do other main stuff, or print error message
    }
}
```

Then, from the command line:

```
$ java [MyPackage.]MyClass MY_METHOD
```

Will run your method.

This is pretty hackish - I'm almost sure it's not what you want to do, but hey, it answers the question, right?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd consider this a hack....  I mean, you have to know the method name, and it's not very scalable.  Does it poke a hole in security?

Comment: What if you need to return a value to the caller?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bash function that lets you do just that:

```
function javae {
  TDIR=`mktemp -d`
  echo "public class Exec { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { " $1 "; } }" > $TDIR/Exec.java && javac $TDIR/Exec.java && java -cp $CLASSPATH:$TDIR Exec;
  rm -r $TDIR;
}
```

Put that in ~/.bashrc and you can do this:

```
javae 'System.out.println(5)'
```

Or this:

```
javae 'class z { public void run() { System.out.println("hi"); } }; (new z()).run()'
```

It's a hack of course, but it works.

Comment: Interesting... but I think you're going to have headaches trying to deal with any non-built-in classes.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot invoke even the main method from the command. The JVM invokes the main method. Its just a convention. It always needs to be "public static void main".

What is your use case?

Answer (score 3):

No you cant

As per [Java command line FAQ](http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-CommandLine.shtml#mainnameconvention) (which is dead now.)
You can check [Java Threads FAQ](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=-2rB5VBNaBgC&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The entry point method main() is used to the provide a standard convention for starting Java programs. The choice of the method name is somewhat arbitrary, but is partly designed to avoid clashes with the Thread start() and Runnable run() methods, for example.

Check the FAQ. You will get some good knowledge about JAVA command line

Comment: the FAQ link is dead :(

Comment: Thank you for updating your post.   Unfortunately this second link may require a book purchase.  “You have either reached a page that is unavailable or you have reached your view limit for this book.”

Answer (score 3):

From [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#51579)

> The Java virtual machine starts up by creating an initial class, which
>   is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the
>   bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1). The Java virtual machine then links
>   the initial class, initializes it, and invokes its public class method
>   void main(String[]). The invocation of this method drives all further
>   execution. Execution of the Java virtual machine instructions
>   constituting the main method may cause linking (and consequently
>   creation) of additional classes and interfaces, as well as invocation
>   of additional methods.

So main appears to be special.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think so.  main() is the entry point.  That's defined by the language.  You can wrap a script around the main() call ("java MyApp arg1...argn"), of course, to obscure the name (and even hide that you're using Java) and to provide your own parameter syntax and parsing -- that is a capability provided by the OS, of course, through some sort of command-line scripting language.

If you use Java to create other types of executables, like Applets or GWT applications, then the entry point is different, but I think you're thinking specifically about executables run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

Please see the Java language specification

[http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html)

Ofcourse applets and servlets and other technologies may have different starting points.