# execute jar without a main?

Tags: java, jar, program-entry-point, executable-jar

Can I execute a jar file without having a main class, in this way:

```
java -jar my_jar.jar -getX arg1 arg2 ...
```

Knowing that I have a method called getX with takes arg1 arg2 ... as arguments.
Any idea?

Comment: "every java program starts with a main method", isn't it?

Comment: indeed, but I want to just call some methods

Comment: call them inside the main method

Comment: the main is the function which call this method

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054703/can-i-invoke-a-java-method-other-than-main-from-the-command-line

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of this? Just testing a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a main method.

The signature for main needs to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Insert code here
}
```

Therefore, you can call your method getX inside the main method.

Comment: I think OP know the signature

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no...but...

Here is a technique you can use to pass a method name and parameters on the command line when invoking the jar.  This instructional example will take a method name as the 1st parameter.  Tweak as necessary and add error checking/handling as needed.

```
package com.charles.example;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodRouter {

public void myMethod(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Amazing!! " + args[1]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        args = new String[2];
        args[0] = "myMethod";
        args[1] = "yoyo-yada-bla";
    }
    final MethodRouter methodRouter = new MethodRouter();
    final Class<?>[] types = { String[].class };
    final Class<?> _class = methodRouter.getClass();
    final String methodName = args[0];
    final Method _method = _class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, types);
    if (_method != null) {
        _method.invoke(methodRouter, new Object[] { args });
    }
}

}
```

Output:

```
Amazing!! yoyo-yada-bla
```

Comment: @rcorbellini If you are asking will changing "types={String[].class};" to "types={args.getClass()};" also work.  The answer is yes.  I think args will always be String[] in this scenario.  But I like your way better.  Good tweak.  Thanks.

Comment: change "_class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, types);" to "_class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, args.getClass());"

Answer (score 0):

There should be atleast one class with a main method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a method just by passing it as an argument. You have to parse your arguments `-getX arg1 arg2` witch is passed to your main method in the parameter `args`, if interpret them yourself to execute the method you want.

If the class with the main method is not in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: some.pack.age.MainClass
```

then you can specify it (full qualified) as the first argument.

```
java -cp my_jar.jar some.pack.age.MainClass -getX arg1 arg2 ...
```

If there is no class with a main method in a jar then you can't execute it. the JVM needs an entry point to start execution and this is the main method. such a jar is just a library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want this, but you could set up a **Unit Test** project, and call your methods from it. That should (sort of) let you execute the methods, without an (explicit) Main method.

Your test-runner will still include an (implicit?) Main method though, which will then be the entry-point for the execution of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to execute a jar using "`java -jar`", you're going to need to define a main class. You'll need a main class that defines a main method for the jar to be executable this way.

You can however, execute a class within a jar (provided they have a main method), using the following syntax:

```
java -classpath my_jar.jar com.project.MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a proxy jar that dynamically links to your jar and calls methods from it. The proxy jar **will** have to have a class with `main` method though.