# Passing cmd line arguments to specific method

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

In java, you can pass cmd line arguments to the `main()` method during program startup.

I'd like to pass cmd line arguments to a specific method that I call from a script directly. I'd had no luck just entering them as I would for `main()`.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // args is cmd line input
        // do stuff with args
    }
}
```

You would do: `~]# java Test cmdlineinput`

I need to do:

```
public class Test {
    public void someMethod(String input) {
        // do stuff with input
    }
}
```

I want to do: `~]# java Test.someMethod cmdlineinput`

Is this possible and how so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program needs a main method to run, and you have to pass the command line arguments directly or indirectly from the main method to wherever you desire it to go. I know of no other solution.

i.e.,

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Test test = new Test();
  test.someMethod(args);
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to call a method directly on the Class from the command-line, which is odd but that's what he is saying

Comment: @Brian: I think you're right, but as I state in my answer, afaik, this can't be done. It sure as heck would be nice to have some context though, you know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338025/2591612

Comment: @Brian: I'll be damned. Why don't you embellish on this and make it an answer?

Comment: CLI parsing inside of business code smells.

Comment: @TimBender: I've not heard of this code smell. Do you have a link for this so I can learn more?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell
http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reusability
The question, is that `String` argument the real parameter to the method? Or will it be parsed into the proper inputs? Would I have to `toString` the real parameters to use that bit of code elsewhere in a program?

Comment: @TimBender What? If you're using Windows, Linux/Unix, or Mac OSX, half of the programs you use on a daily basis take cmd line arguments, they are just abstracted via UI of some sort.

Comment: @TimBender also, as far as I know, String is the only data type that can be passed into a program via the cmd line. It would be up to the program to attempt data conversion if necessary (ie, parse an Integer out of String, ensuring it's a number, etc).

Comment: @TimBender: None of those links states that you can't use the arguments as shown.

Comment: @GIJoe: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think perhaps his argument is that using naked Strings as surrogates for what should be non-String data, is not clean.

Comment: @SnakeDoc lol. I was referencing the idea of using a REPL to call `someMethod` directly. This answer should be the accepted answer. My guess is that the OP has presented an "XY Problem" and `main` would suffice if they knew how exec java in a script.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Precisely! The point of `main` (imo) is to be that layer which parses the String inputs and sets up the rest of the application to run. In addition to the obvious of providing a standardized entry-point for the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, the JVM will look for `main` and call that. You can't call methods directly from the command-line. However, if you use a REPL for the JVM such as Groovy and `groovysh` you can call methods from within the shell. This may or may not work for your use case. However, it would technically allow you to individually call Java methods and invoke them. Read more at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338025/2591612).