# How to call public static String method from jar from command-line?

Tags: java, jar, static

We have a project (say, **Foo**) which has some `public static` methods, some of them return `String`. Now, I need to access that project's `jar` from command-line and call one of those `public static String` methods to get that String.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I need to pass that returned string as an argument to a shell script. Something like this:

```
./my_bash_script.sh <value returned from jar> <more arguments>
```

---

How do we do it?

Tried to call the jar from command-line, but that didn't help.

```
java -cp Foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName

Error: Could not find or load main class jar
```

It was expected, since the class doesn't have a Main function.

Also tried to add a wrapper around the **Foo.jar**. Like, added this jar (Foo.jar) in my other project as a dependency, and called `public static String` method from `Foo.jar`. Well, this works, but I have to return a String outside Java application and Main has to be `void`.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Please ask for more explanation, if I have left out any detail, before down-voting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I invoke a java method other than main() from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054703/can-i-invoke-a-java-method-other-than-main-from-the-command-line)

Comment: What does "I have to return a String outside Java application" mean? If you have another application that needs to read from this Java application, does it take stdin/out which could be redirected?

Comment: @specializt: Sadly, I cannot use Groovy.

Comment: Isn't Main() always void? You can print your "string" to stdout and read it. How are you planning to get hold of that "string"?

Comment: @AdrianPang: Details added

Comment: Execute your jar (via the wrapper). Store the stuff in a file (or any stream). Pipe it for next steps. Do you have control over the shell script? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/how-to-pipe-output-from-one-process-to-another-but-only-execute-if-the-first-has

Comment: @TJ-: Yes, I do have control over shell script

Comment: perfect. Pipe the output of the wrapper execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest solution would be : create & compile a new java console application as JAR, include your other JAR and

```
System.out.println
```

the output from it, easy as cake.
After that you can start your new JAR with

```
java -jar FILE.jar
```

and have the output just the way you need it

Comment: I was able to print out the output but forgot that stdout can be taken by shell as argument. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a main method that passes a command line parameter to the method and then does a `System.out.println(result)`.

A more general solution would require a wrapper that used reflection to invoke the right method and print out the result.

You could do that via something like this:

```
public class InvokeMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        String clazz = args[0];
        String method = args[1];
        String[] methodArgs = new String[args.length - 2];
        Class<?>[] methodParam = new Class[args.length - 2];
        for (int i = 2; i<args.length; i++) {
            methodArgs[i-2] = args[i];
            methodParam[i-2] = String.class;
        }

        Class<?> c = Class.forName(clazz);
        Method m = c.getMethod(method, methodParam);
        String result = (String) m.invoke(methodParam);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Compile that and package it into invoke.jar and then you can just do `java -cp invoke.jar:your_real_jar.jar InvokeMethod some.class.Here method_name arg1 arg2 arg3...`

Comment: Thanks for the respone Alcanzar. Looks like specializt's answer is more straight forward. +1 for your reply.

Comment: His is definitely easier, but if you have multiple times you have to write a wrapper, simpler just to write it once.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the output of the wrapper to your shell script.

Java

```
// -- Test.java ----
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Call the method from Foo.jar here
        System.out.println("Hello" + " World");
    }
}
```

Shell

```
# ----- test.sh ------
#!/bin/sh
grep "$1" input.txt
```

input.txt

```
# Sample Input
Line 1 : Hello World
Line 2 : Here is Hello World Again
Line 3 : This is not Hello + World
Line 4 : AB Hello World CD
```

Commands

```
javac Test.java
./test.sh "`java Test`" # Note the `
```

Sample o/p

```
Line 1 : Hello World
Line 2 : Here is Hello World Again
Line 4 : AB Hello World CD
```